# Bibliography using biber not appearing

Tags: bibliographies, biber

I'm trying to create a bibliography using TeXworks and biber on Windows 10. I keep getting errors and I just do not understand. I can work with latex but have no experience with bibliographies so the problem can absolutely be a stupid error on my part.
This is everything in my tex file:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[british]{babel}
\usepackage[autostyle]{csquotes}
\usepackage[natbib,hyperref,sorting=none]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{quellen.bib}
\usepackage{hyperref} 
\begin{document} 
nothing
\nocite{*}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

This is everything in quellen.bib:

```
@book{Horn1985,
   author = {Roger A. Horn and Charles R. Johnson},
   doi = {10.1017/CBO9780511810817},
   isbn = {9780521386326},
   month = {12},
   note = {Schur decomp},
   pages = {79-80},
   publisher = {Cambridge University Press},
   title = {Matrix Analysis},
   year = {1985},
}
```

Running with biber I have seen:
ERROR - main.bcf is malformed, last biblatex run probably failed. Deleted main.bbl
But currently I don't get any errors but there simply is no bibliography.

What can I do? What information have I forgotten to provide?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Unfortunately, I am unable to replicate the issue you've encountered. Please tell us more about your TeX distribution. (TeXworks is *not* a TeX distribution.) Do you use TeXLive or MikTeX? Do you use pdfLaTeX, XeLaTeX, or LuaLaTeX to compile the document? Which versions of `biblatex` and `biber` do you employ? FWIW: I use MacTeX2020, pdfLaTeX, biblatex v3.16, and biber v2.16. Note that it's *not* a coincidence that the decimal digits of the versions of biblatex and biber  are the same; if they're not the same on your system, something bad is likely going on.

Comment: The code shared in the question so far looks fine and compiles as expected for me. You should definitely not be getting this Biber error from running pdfLaTeX, Biber, pdfLaTeX, pdfLaTeX on this example code in an empty folder. Delete the temporary files (`.aux`, `.bbl`, `.bcf`, ...) and try to run the compile cycle again. If there are any errors during any of the runs, report them here in full (direct copies from the `.log` or `.blg` files). ...

Comment: ... Errors like this usually appear when the LaTeX run was aborted prematurely due to an error. In this case it is usually best to first delete all temporary files then to fix the error that stopped the LaTeX compilation. Only after LaTeX compiles without error should you start running Biber again.

Comment: @moewe Thank you for the quick response and fairly reassuring answer. I've done exactly as you advised and don't have any errors but also don't have a bibliography.

Comment: @Mico Sorry for not including all the necessary information. I use MiKTeX 2.9 and pdfLaTeX to compile. In the automatically generated .tex file it says biblatex v3.14 but there is no mention of biber. I'm assuming that is exactly the issue here, that I haven't properly told my program to use biber but I don't know what exactly it is I need to do then. Biber is listed as a processing tool in texworks though.

Comment: OK. Please run the exact MWE you posted in a new empty folder with pdfLaTeX, Biber, pdfLaTeX, pdfLaTeX and upload both the complete `.log` file and `.blg` file to a text sharing website such as https://pastebin.com/, https://gist.github.com/, ...

Comment: Any news here? With the details shared so far we can only offer guesses as to what might have been wrong. As mentioned above, the code posted so far looks OK. We need to see the raw `.log` and `.blg` files to be able to say more.

Comment: I don't fully understand how but it works now. In a previous run the bib file had an entry with mathematical symbols such as ∞ but it was written as it is here rather than $\infty$ as in LaTeX. That lead to some problems

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the problem at hand cannot be reproduced with the information shared in the question so far. Apparently the OP managed to get the bibliography up and running, so this question is no longer relevant and unlikely to help future visitors in its current state.